# How to Implement Pagination in DotNet MVC

Tags: .net, pagination

I have a code wherein I get a few details from the database in a tabular form in HTML. I want to implement Pagination to the same and am unable to do so.

Thanks in Advance.

Following is my code for **Index** where I am getting my data in an object.

```
public ActionResult Index(SearchPostedJob objSearchPostedJob)
    {
        Result res = null;
        try
        {
            objSearchPostedJob.page = (objSearchPostedJob.page == null ? 1 : objSearchPostedJob.page);
            ViewBag.SearchPostedJob = objSearchPostedJob;
            res = objPostedJobDAL.GetPostedJobs(ApplicationSession.CurrentUser.RecruiterId);

            if (res.Status)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = Common.GetMessage(res.MessageId, "[Master]", "Keyword");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Common.WriteLog(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
        return View(res.Results);
    }
```

And Following is my code on HTML where I am displaying the data with some other details in a Tabular Format:

```
@model IEnumerable<NurseOneStop.SC.PostedJob>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
    <div class="postjob-form">

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "PostedJob", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="j_search" style="margin-left:3%;">
        <input class="form-control" name="SearchKeyword" id="SearchKeyword" placeholder="Search Keyword" />
    </div>
    <div class="j_search">
        <input id="pinput1" name="JobLocation" class="form-control" type="text" value="@ViewBag.SearchPostedJob.JobLocation" placeholder="Enter a location">
        <input id="Latitude" name="Latitude" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.SearchPostedJob.Latitude">
        <input id="Longitude" name="Longitude" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.SearchPostedJob.Longitude">
    </div>
    <div class="j_search">
        <select class="form-control" name="Experience" id="Experience">
            <option value="" selected>Select Experience</option>
            @for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                <option value="@i" @(ViewBag.SearchPostedJob.Experience == i ? "selected" : "")>@i</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="j_search">
        <select class="form-control" name="Salary" id="Salary">
            <option value="" selected>Select Salary</option>
            @for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                <option value="@i" @(ViewBag.SearchPostedJob.Salary == i ? "selected" : "")>@i</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="add-btn"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="~/PostedJob/Save?returnUrl=/PostedJob/Index">Add New Opening</a></div>

    @*<div class="srch-btn"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button></div>*@
}
</div>

<div>

<table class="table" id="myTable">
    <tr>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.JobTitle)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.JobLocation)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NumberOfPositions)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ValidFrom)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ValidTo)<br />
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.JobReference)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
        </th>
        <th>
            Application
        </th>
        <th>
            CloneJob
        </th>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobTitle)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobLocation)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumberOfPositions)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ValidFrom)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ValidTo)<br />

                @* @Html.ActionLink("Delete Resume", "DeleteResume", new { ResumeId = Model.ResumeId, returnUrl = "/Nurse/ProfileView" }, new { @class = "btnViewJobDetails" })*@
                @if (!item.IsExtendJob)
                {


                    @Html.ActionLink("ExtendJob", "ExtendJob", new { PostedJobId = item.PostedJobId, IsExtendJob = item.IsExtendJob, returnUrl = "/PostedJob/Index" }, new { @class = "btnViewJobDetails" })
                }
                else
                {
                    <span class="pull-right" style="font-weight:bold; color:red;">JobExtended</span>
                }

            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobReference)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Applied(" + item.AppliedCnt + ")", "JobView", new { PostedJobId = item.PostedJobId, returnUrl = "/PostedJob/Index" }, new { @class = "btnViewJobDetails" })

            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("JobClone", "CloneJob", new { PostedJobId = item.PostedJobId, returnUrl = "/PostedJob/Index" }, new { @class = "btnViewJobDetails" })
            </td>

        </tr>
        }

    </table>
</div>


@section Scripts
 {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        function initMap() {
            var input = document.getElementById('pinput1');
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
            autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                console.log(JSON.stringify(place));
                if (!place.geometry) {
                    window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
                    return;
                }
                var latlong = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(place.geometry.location));
                document.getElementById('Latitude').value = latlong.lat;
                document.getElementById('Longitude').value = latlong.lng;
            });
        }
        initMap();
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#SearchKeyword").on("keyup", function () {
                var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                $("#myTable tr").filter(function () {
                    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#pinput1").on("keyup", function () {
                var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                $("#myTable tr").filter(function () {
                    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Not mandatory but highly recommend: first step is to render table body client side from an object array. Second step: accept pageIndex and possibly pageSize in your GET. Third: get data with an AJAX call. Fourth: now should be trivial to add pagination buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Do pagination as following guide from Microsoft:
[Microsoft pagination tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make changes in Index method to accept page number and page size as parameters as below(and pass it using query string)

```
public ActionResult Index(SearchPostedJob objSearchPostedJob, int pageSize, int pageNumber)
{
    Result res = null;
    try
    {
        objSearchPostedJob.page = (objSearchPostedJob.page == null ? 1 : objSearchPostedJob.page);
        ViewBag.SearchPostedJob = objSearchPostedJob;
        res = objPostedJobDAL.GetPostedJobs(ApplicationSession.CurrentUser.RecruiterId, pageNumber, pageSize); //Changes in DAL are required

        if (res.Status)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = Common.GetMessage(res.MessageId, "[Master]", "Keyword");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Common.WriteLog(ex);
        throw ex;
    }
    return View(res.Results);
}
```

Then make changes in DAL to only serve the number of objects as required. Then using html/jquery you can create a pager which will create link for 1st, last, next and previous pages.